# Hiding existing windows 7 and loading decoy windows 7 instead

Tags: encryption

I have windows 7 64bit installed on my computer (NTFS).
I wish to hide this installation and create a "decoy" windows 7:

When the computer boots up, it will boot to this new "decoy" win 7.
If, on the other hand, when the computer boot up, I will insert a USB driver with a loader - it will load up a password screen in which after writing the correct one it will open the existing, hidden win 7.

I looked at DiskCryptor but I was only able to password protect the default OS.
Is it possible to do such thing?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use a VM inside the decoy ? (which could be "OS encrypted" by Truecrypt AND installed in a Truecrypt volume)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use TrueCrypt with a hidden volume which provides you with “plausible deniability” If you would be forced to unlock your drive, you can enter the password to the "decoy" operating system. Using a VM is optional.

[image: Standard vs Standard & Hidden volume]

The difference between a standard TrueCrypt volume and a TrueCrypt volume after adding a hidden volume.

[image]

You can create this volume by selecting the option "Hidden TrueCrypt volume" in the TrueCrypt Volume Creation Wizard.

A lot of websites claim that TrueCrypt is no longer secure, however, I have yet to see someone break a fully encrypted disk.

Also [recent documents](http://thinkprogress.org/world/2014/12/29/3607160/new-snowden-documents-show-nsa-proof-encryption-exists/) reveal that the NSA can't break TrueCrypt volumes, assuming strong passwords are used.

TrueCrypt can be download [here](https://truecrypt.ch/downloads/) as the original website no longer offers it.